# Firebase error when calling updateEmail()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

After a long authorization session, I try to update the email and get this error:

[*error*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlp7i.jpg)

Obviously, Firebase wants me to do a reauthorization. Will it be valid to redirect users to the Sing In page?

Or there are any other ways to make that more valid as true Oauth2 requires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to authentication, there are some operations that are considered sensitive. Updating a user’s email is indeed a security-sensitive operation that requires a recent login from the user. So for such an operation, you should reauthenticate the users.

> Will it be valid to redirect the user to the Sing In page?

There are two solutions here, you either reauthenticate the user by asking for the credentials or you can sign the user out and let it authenticate again.